# How can I make discord bot respond none?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

Right now I am working on a **userinfo command**. I am currently working on a server roles portion inside my **embed**. When I have a role assigned the command works fine.

When I have no role assigned the spot should say **none** but instead breaks the bot. I can see that it is not sending `None` and I am unsure what to do.

Can someone get me pointed in the right direction please?

Code:

```js
{
    name: `**User Roles (${roles.length}):**`,
    value: `${roles.length < 10 ? roles.join(', ') : roles.length > 10 ? this.client.utils.trimArray(roles) : 'None'}`
},
```

Error:

```
F:\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\MessageEmbed.js:432
    if (!value) throw new RangeError('EMBED_FIELD_VALUE');
                      ^
RangeError [EMBED_FIELD_VALUE]: MessageEmbed field values may not be empty.
    at Function.normalizeField (F:\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\MessageEmbed.js:432:23)
    at F:\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\MessageEmbed.js:452:14
    at Array.map (<anonymous>)
    at MessageEmbed.addFields (F:\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\structures\MessageEmbed.js:266:42)
    at Object.execute (F:\DiscordBot\commands\userinfo.js:46:14)
    at Client.<anonymous> (F:\DiscordBot\main.js:43:41)
    at Client.emit (node:events:526:28)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (F:\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (F:\DiscordBot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32) {
  [Symbol(code)]: 'EMBED_FIELD_VALUE'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your current code results in an empty string when there are no roles, and results in 'None' when there are excalty 10 roles. Discordjs can't send an empty message that's why it throws an error.

```js
function test(roles){
  let obj = { name: `**User Roles (${roles.length}):**`, value: `${roles.length < 10 ? roles.join(', ') : roles.length > 10 ? this.client.utils.trimArray(roles) : 'None'}` };
console.log(obj);
}
test([]);
test([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]);
```

Here's how you could achieve what you want:

```js
{
    name: `**User Roles (${roles.length}):**`,
    value: `${
      roles.length == 0 ?
        'None' :
        roles.length < 10 ?
            roles.join(', ') :
            this.client.utils.trimArray(roles)
    }` 
}
```

I advise you not to write long lines of code as they can be very unreadable and error-prone

Comment: Thank you so much for the response. I worked it back into the 1 line code and got it working. I really appreciate your help. Thank you so much!!!